# Транслитерация на jquery

Tags: jquery

Помогите решить проблему. Есть форма добавления поста. Нужно реализовать на jquery функцию транслитерации, так что бы привводе текста в поле "Title" автоматически заполнялось поле "slug url" но в транслите. Причем таблица символов для транслитерации находится в php файле, в лэнг файле, в виде масива:

```
$i18['TRANSLIT'] = array (
  'А'=>'a','Б'=>'b','В'=>'v',
    'Г'=>'g','Д'=>'d','Е'=>'e','Ё'=>'yo','Ж'=>'zh',
    'З'=>'z','И'=>'i','Й'=>'j','К'=>'k','Л'=>'l',
    'М'=>'m','Н'=>'n','О'=>'o','П'=>'p','Р'=>'r',
    'С'=>'s','Т'=>'t','У'=>'u','Ф'=>'f','Х'=>'h',
    'Ц'=>'c','Ч'=>'ch','Ш'=>'sh','Щ'=>'shh','Ъ'=>'',
    'Ы'=>'y','Ь'=>'','Э'=>'e','Ю'=>'yu','Я'=>'ya',
    'а'=>'a','б'=>'b','в'=>'v','г'=>'g','д'=>'d',
    'е'=>'e','ё'=>'yo','ж'=>'zh','з'=>'z','и'=>'i',
    'й'=>'j','к'=>'k','л'=>'l','м'=>'m','н'=>'n',
    'о'=>'o','п'=>'p','р'=>'r','с'=>'s','т'=>'t',
    'у'=>'u','ф'=>'f','х'=>'h','ц'=>'c','ч'=>'ch',
    'ш'=>'sh','щ'=>'shh','ъ'=>'','ы'=>'y','ь'=>'',
    'э'=>'e','ю'=>'yu','я'=>'ya',' '=>'-','-'=>'-','»'=>'',
    '.'=>'.'
);
```

подключаю его на странице так:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var dict = "<?php echo json_encode($i18['TRANSLIT']); ?>";
}
// Здесь должен быть код транслитерации
</script>
```

Вот теперь мне нужен сам ког транслитерации и функцией автоматического заполнения поля "slug".

P.S. я совсем не программист и ни одного языка программирования не знаю... так лишь поверхностно...

Comment: авто заполнение я решил так:

$("#title").keyup(function() {
    var slug_name = $(this).val();
    $("#slug").val(slug_name);
});

Comment: Есть уже, http://habrahabr.ru/post/73168/ -  можно поизучать, а можно просто применить.

Comment: Да я знаю про этот плагин, в данный момент им и пользуюсь, но мне он немного не подходит, так как мне нужно не только для русского языка. Еще мне надо то же самое сделать для элемента <label>, а как заставить этот плагин работать с ним, я не разобрался.